# SQL UPDATE not working?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In my LAMP application (using CodeIgniter), I have a call to $this->db->update... that generates a SQL like the following:

```
UPDATE `MyTable` SET `MyProcess` = 5 WHERE `Id` = 1
```

The problem is that this seems to work intermittently -- and I currently have no idea what might be wrong. Is there anything about MySQL I need to know about when trying to update? I'm adding & updating records a lot (but probably no more than one query every 5 seconds). When I run the query in phpMyAdmin, it works fine.

Comment: Can you post your actual code, including the assertion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an addition to Mark's answer. `mysql_affected_rows` also returns `0` if you try to update a record but the values in that record do not change.

For example; current values in `MyTable`:

```
+----+-----------+
| ID | MyProcess |
+----+-----------+
| 1  | 5         |
+----+-----------+
```

Then when you run your query:

```
UPDATE `MyTable` SET `MyProcess` = 5 WHERE `Id` = 1
```

`mysql_affected_rows` will return `0`

Could this be what is happening in your case?

Comment: It was. I was incrementing a counter in the DB field. My approach was wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that can catch people out is that if your `id` for some reason doesn't exist in the table you won't get any error from the `UPDATE` statement - it will just silently do nothing.

You can use for example [`mysql_affected_rows`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) (or equivalent for your database API) to see that a row was in fact updated, and if not display or log an error message. This should help you troubleshoot your problem.

Comment: The table has 1 record. It has id = 1. The reason I caught this error is by putting an assert right after the update. I asserted that the affected rows should be 1. Assertion fails sometimes.

Comment: When the assertion fails, is the affected number of rows zero, or more than one?

Comment: Also, does the table absolutely always have one record? You're never deleting or inserting from the table, just updating?